# Is there a free software that will let me solve thermodynamic cycles?

Tags: software

is there a free software that would let me calculate pressure, volume, and temperature at "corners" of a thermodynamic cycle as well as calculate efficiency and other parameters, given some input data?

Comment: Yes, I did it for parts of engine performance calculations - used Excel and had to type in a lot of property data

Comment: Same - you can use Google docs or libre office if Excel isn't free for you (i.e. you don't have it already)

Comment: And then "enjoyed" writing an interpolation function as the property data was in 5 or 10 degree steps...